# file not found exception in jar

Tags: java, file-io, classpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [file not found exception in jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755806/file-not-found-exception-in-jar)

hi
I created one class ABC in that i have one constructor,
and in the constructor I have one xml file,
when I run my jar it is giving error :
file not found 
please tell me solution...